# Only trigger mouseleave when menu wrapper is leaved

Tags: jquery, mouseleave, mouseout

I have a very basic navigation with two main menu items.

When you hover main menu item 1, I toggle visibility of #sub-menu1.
When you hover main menu item 2, I toggle visibility of #sub-menu2.

Like so:

```
$(".wrapper .main #m li").mouseenter(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var menu = that.attr("class");

    if(menu == "first") {
        $("#s1").css("display","block");
        $("#s2").css("display","none");
    }

    if(menu == "second") {
        $("#s1").css("display","none");
        $("#s2").css("display","block");
    }
});
```

**My issue:** I only want to trigger `mouseleave` when either the main menu or the sub menu is leaved.
My objective is to hover my main menu item and be able to hover down on the sub menu without `mouseleave` triggering.

This is what i´ve tried with:

```
$(".wrapper").mouseleave(function() {
    console.log("leave");

    $("#s1").css("display","none");
    $("#s2").css("display","none");
});
```

As you can see `mouseleave` is triggering the same moment the main menu is leaved.

http://jsfiddle.net/17krr02p/

HTML is as so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <ul id="m">
            <li class="first">main 1</li>
            <li class="second">main 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sub">
        <ul id="s1">
            <li>sub 1-1</li>
            <li>sub 1-2</li>
            <li>sub 1-3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="s2">
            <li>sub 2-1</li>
            <li>sub 2-2</li>
            <li>sub 2-3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/17krr02p/3/)-

First you had some issues on your CSS : placing `absolute` positioning make the elements go 'out of the flow';

Then to solve the problem you had on mouseleave, in order to achieve to arrive to submenu (since you had a gap) I applied a little delay.